# busqueda en un array c++

Tags: c++, array, estructuras-de-datos

tengo este codigo. Al ingresar unicamente 1 paciente anda correctamente. El problema comienza cuando ingreso mas de uno. Por ejemplo si ingreso 3 pacientes, y luego quiero buscar por ejemplo al segundo para eliminarlo a traves del dni, no lo encuentra, y tampoco al tercero, solo al primero ingresado.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>
#include <time.h>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;


const long int MAX = 10000;

//STRUCTS
struct paciente{
    string nombre;
    string apellido;
    int dni;
    int telefono;
};

void agregar(paciente arreglo[], int &tamano){
    int dnimientras, corte;

    cout << "cuantos ingreso: "; cin >> corte;

    for (int i = 0; i < corte; i++){
            cout << "Ingrese su nombre: "; getline(cin >> ws, arreglo[i].nombre);
            cout << "Ingrese su apellido: "; getline(cin >> ws, arreglo[i].apellido);
            cout << "Ingrese su DNI: "; cin >> dnimientras;
            for (int k = 0; k < tamano; k++){
            while (dnimientras == arreglo[k].dni){
                cout << "Ese DNI ya se encuentra en el sistema. Ingrese otro: "; cin >> dnimientras;
            }}
            arreglo[i].dni = dnimientras;
            cout << "Ingrese su numero de telefono: "; cin >> arreglo[i].telefono; 

            arreglo[tamano].nombre = arreglo[i].nombre;
            arreglo[tamano].apellido = arreglo[i].apellido;
            arreglo[tamano].telefono = arreglo[i].telefono;
            arreglo[tamano].dni = arreglo[i].dni;
            tamano++;      
    }
}

bool busscar(paciente arreglo[], int &tamano, int elim){
    for (int i = 0; i < tamano; i++){
       if (arreglo[i].dni == elim)
            return true;
    return false;
    }
}

void eliminar(paciente arreglo[], int &tamano, int elem){
    for (int i = 0; i < tamano; i++){
        if (arreglo[i].dni == elem){
            for (int k = i; k < (tamano-1); k++){
                arreglo[k].dni = arreglo[k+1].dni;
                arreglo[k].apellido = arreglo[k+1].apellido;
                arreglo[k].nombre = arreglo[k+1].nombre;
                arreglo[k].telefono = arreglo[k+1].telefono;
            }
            tamano--;
            break;
        }
    }
}

void mostrar(paciente datos[], int &dimlog){
    for (int i = 0; i < dimlog; i++){
        cout << "Nombre: " << datos[i].nombre << endl;
        cout << "Apellido: " << datos[i].apellido << endl;
        cout << "DNI:" << datos[i].dni << endl;
        cout << "Numero de telefono: " << datos[i].telefono << endl;
        i++;
    }
}

int main(){
    paciente datos[MAX];
    int dimlog = 0;
    int elim;
    int deseo;

    agregar(datos, dimlog);
    mostrar(datos, dimlog);

    cout << "Ingrese su DNI para darse de baja: "; cin >> elim;
    if (busscar(datos, dimlog, elim)){
        mostrar(datos, elim);
        cout << " 1 para eliminarse. De lo contrario, 2" << endl; cin >> deseo; 
        if (deseo == 1){
            eliminar(datos, dimlog, elim);
            cout << "La operacion se realizo con exito" << endl;
        }
    }
    else{
        cout << "El paciente no se encuentra en el sistema" << endl;

}}
```

Ademas, cuando invoco la funcion de mostrar pacientes, mi deseo es que se muestre el arreglo entero, y solo me muestra tambien el primero ingresado. Pienso que el problema esta en como estoy manejando la dimension logica, pero no logro darme cuenta. Muchas gracias!!

Comment: Hola. Te recomiendo usar un `std::vector<paciente> datos;` para almacenar los pacientes. Eso va a simplificar el código, y va a disminuir la probabildad de que tenga errores. Y tendrías que cambiar la función a `void agregar(std::vector<paciente>& arreglo)`

Comment: el problema es ese. me piden que sea con arreglos estaticos

Comment: Veo algunos errores: 1) en la función `bool busscar()`, el `return false;` está en la posición incorrecta. 2) en `void mostrar()`, hay un `i++;` en un ciclo `for` que ya tiene un `i++`

Comment: @PatricioLoncomilla Puedes escribirlo en una respuesta?

Comment: @RainbowBap ¿Cómo que te piden programar con una estructura de datos concreta?